# Form.Show() hangs new form instance

Tags: c#

So I have this class called **Common.cs** in that class I have a function that creates an instance of a form, **frmMainGame.cs**, which then calls a method that should invoke this new form instance, but for some reason, it does not. So when the form is shown using **mainGame.Show();** the form just hangs there and I can't do anything with it.

Here's the code:

**frmMainGame.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace Ghoul_Engine
{ 

public partial class frmMainGame : Form
{

 public delegate void openGame();
 public delegate void refreshGame();
 public delegate void updateScreen(Bitmap image);

 drawing draw;


 public bool isTyping = false;


    public Graphics g;

    public List<String> Chat = new List<String>();

    public List<String> chat
    {
        get { return Chat; }
    }

    public frmMainGame()
    {

        draw = new drawing(this);

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public Size size{
        get { return this.Size; }
    }

    public void showGame()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invoke");
            BeginInvoke(new openGame(showGame), null);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Show();
            this.Focus();
        }
    }


    public void refresh()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new refreshGame(refresh), null);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
    private void frmMainGame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        draw.drawText(new string[] { "GHOUL Game Engine Alpha V0.0.1" }, 12, 0, 0, Brushes.Yellow);
        clientNetHandler handlers = new clientNetHandler();

    }

    public void update(Bitmap image)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new updateScreen(update), new object[] { image });
        }
        else
        {
            pbScreen.Image = image;
        }
    }


    private void frmMainGame_Close(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

        Program.Network.Send("logout", Program.netHandlers.getDataByte(clientNetHandler.cNetType.Logout));
        //Program.Network.closeSocket();
        Program.mainMenu.showMainMenu();
        Program.mainGame = new frmMainGame();
    }

    private void tmrRefreshScreen_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void frmMainGame_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pbScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        draw.drawText(Chat.ToArray(), 12, 0, 30, Brushes.Green);
    }
}
}
```

**Common.Cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Ghoul_Engine
{
class Common
{


     public Common()
    {
    }
     public void innnitiateGame(String login)
     {

         Program.mainMenu.hideMainMenu();
         frmMainGame mainGame = new frmMainGame();
         mainGame.showGame();
     }

    public void preExit()
    {
            Program.Network.closeSocket();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a **message pump**, which is created by passing a form instance to `Application.Run()`:

```
     Application.Run(new frmMainGame());
```

Comment: If I do that then I can't access my network class created in Program. It waits until the frmMainGame closes before running anything in the class that way.

Comment: I agree with @dotNET, you need to restructure the way you've got things.  Application.Run() isn't optional if you've got forms involved.  If your communication isn't working until the main form is closed then you're doing something really unconventional and we'd need more details to figure that out...

Comment: @DylanDodds start you network code in another thread before calling `Application.Run`

Comment: How would I got about starting a whole class as a new thread?

Comment: A thread points to a method.  Within that method, create your class and "start" it.  Have you even tried to create a thread yet?...

Comment: I did but I really don't think I knew what I was doing with threads. But the problem is I'm using that network class to send data all over my code. So anytime I got to send data using Program.Network.Send() I can't send it because the socket was connected in a different thread.

Comment: I sorta got this working I started the application.run on a new thread and it got the networking running on the old thread which can still modify content on the new form :) the only problem I have now is for some reason the receive data is still showing parts of old data that was already accepted but I don't know why. Anyways that's for another issue, thanks sooo much!

Comment: You really should start the networking thread from within the form thread.  The "life" of the application is tied to the form instance passed to Application.Run().  Doing it the other way around means you could have an application hanging around without a form instance tied to it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to redesign your classes structure a little bit. Instead of creating your main form's instance in Common.cs, I suggest you go ahead with the normal way things flow, i.e. create your main form's instance in program.cs using `Application.Run()` so that it installs a message pump for you, keep your socket communication classes in a separate file (probably like just they are) and then instantiate them within your main form. If you must have these communication classes available across multiple forms, then go on creating their instance(s) in program.cs and pass them to different forms/other modules as parameters.